# Calculating Distances and Filtering and Summing Values Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have data which contains a location name, latitude, longitude and then a number value associated locations. The final goal for me would to get a dataframe that has the sum of the values of each location within specific distance ranges. A sample dataframe is below:

```
IDVALUE,Latitude,Longitude,NumberValue
ID1,44.968046,-94.420307,1
ID2,44.933208,-94.421310,10
ID3,33.755787,-116.359998,15
ID4,33.844843,-116.54911,207
ID5,44.92057,-93.44786,133
ID6,44.240309,-91.493619,52
ID7,44.968041,-94.419696,39
ID8,44.333304,-89.132027,694
ID9,33.755783,-116.360066,245
ID10,33.844847,-116.549069,188
ID11,44.920474,-93.447851,3856
ID12,44.240304,-91.493768,189
```

Firstly, I managed to get the distances between each of them using the haversine function. Using the code below I turned the latlongs into radians and then created a matrix where the diagonals are infinite values.

```
df_latlongs['LATITUDE'] = np.radians(df_latlongs['LATITUDE'])
df_latlongs['LONGITUDE'] = np.radians(df_latlongs['LONGITUDE'])
dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

latlong_df = pd.DataFrame(dist.pairwise(df_latlongs[['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE']].to_numpy())*6373, columns=df_latlongs.IDVALUE.unique(), index=df_latlongs.IDVALUE.unique())

np.fill_diagonal(latlong_df.values, math.inf)
```

This distance matrix is then in kilometres. What I'm struggling with next is to be able to filter the distances of each of the locations and get the total number of values within a range and link this to the original dataframe.

Below is the code I have used to filter the distance matrix to get all of the locations within 500 meters:

```
latlong_df_rows = latlong_df[latlong_df < 0.5]
latlong_df_rows = latlong_df_rows.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
latlong_df_rows = latlong_df_rows.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

My attempt was to them get a list for each location of the locations that were in this value using the code below:

```
within_range_df = latlong_df_rows.apply(lambda row: row[row < 0.05].index.tolist(), axis=1)
within_range_df = within_range_df.to_frame()
within_range_df = within_range_df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)
within_range_df = within_range_df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

From here I was going to try and get the NumberValue from the original dataframe by looping through the list of values to obtain another column for the number for that location. Then sum all of them. The final dataframe would ideally look like the following:

```
ID VALUE,<500m,500-1000m,>100m
ID1,x1,y1,z1
ID2,x2,y2,z2
ID3,x3,y3,z3
ID4,x4,y4,z4
ID5,x5,y5,z5
ID6,x6,y6,z6
ID7,x7,y7,z7
ID8,x8,y8,z8
ID9,x9,y9,z9
ID10,x10,y10,z10
ID11,x11,y11,z11
ID12,x12,y12,z12
```

Where x y and z are the total number values for the nearest locations for different distances. I know this is probably really weird and overcomplicated so any tips to change the question or anything else that is needed I'll be happy to provide. Cheers

Comment: You want to create a BallTree with haversine distance, and query it with radius for each entry. Let me know if you need an example

Comment: This would be very appreciated. I haven't heard of this method before, I'll give it a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a helper function, making use of BallTree, e.g.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
```

We use `query_radius()` to get the IDs and use list comprehension to get the values and sum them;

```
locations_radians = np.radians(df[["Latitude","Longitude"]].values)
tree = BallTree(locations_radians, leaf_size=12, metric='haversine')

def summed_numbervalue_for_radius( radius_in_m=100):
    distance_in_meters = radius_in_m
    earth_radius = 6371000

    radius = distance_in_meters / earth_radius
    
    ids_within_radius = tree.query_radius(locations_radians, r=radius, count_only=False) 
    values_as_array = np.array(df.NumberValue)

    summed_values = [values_as_array[ix].sum() for ix in  ids_within_radius]
    return np.array(summed_values)
```

With the helper function you can do for instance;

```
df = df.assign( sum_100=summed_numbervalue_for_radius(100))
df = df.assign( sum_500=summed_numbervalue_for_radius(500))
df = df.assign( sum_1000=summed_numbervalue_for_radius(1000))
df = df.assign( sum_1000_to_5000=summed_numbervalue_for_radius(5000)-summed_numbervalue_for_radius(1000))
```

Will give you

```
   IDVALUE   Latitude   Longitude  NumberValue  sum_100  sum_500  sum_1000  \
0      ID1  44.968046  -94.420307            1       40       40        40   
1      ID2  44.933208  -94.421310           10       10       10        10   
2      ID3  33.755787 -116.359998           15      260      260       260   
3      ID4  33.844843 -116.549110          207      395      395       395   
4      ID5  44.920570  -93.447860          133     3989     3989      3989   
5      ID6  44.240309  -91.493619           52      241      241       241   
6      ID7  44.968041  -94.419696           39       40       40        40   
7      ID8  44.333304  -89.132027          694      694      694       694   
8      ID9  33.755783 -116.360066          245      260      260       260   
9     ID10  33.844847 -116.549069          188      395      395       395   
10    ID11  44.920474  -93.447851         3856     3989     3989      3989   
11    ID12  44.240304  -91.493768          189      241      241       241   

    sum_1000_to_5000  
0                 10  
1                 40  
2                  0  
3                  0  
4                  0  
5                  0  
6                 10  
7                  0  
8                  0  
9                  0  
10                 0  
11                 0
```

Comment: I will have a go at this, this looks very interesting. This is just sample data and I have a document with quite a lot of rows. With large data (n=5000) or so will I need to be changing the leaf size in order to make sure that runtime is not too high?

Comment: 5000 is not large, above 100.000 maybe leaf size is important

Comment: For 5000, it takes about 10 seconds. Hopefully fast enough